# Understanding the difference between the principal components construction and the Karhunen-Loeve expansion.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm currently studying the book *Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering* by Glasserman. When covering the simulation of Brownian Motions, Glasserman explains the Principal Component Construction (PCC) and the Karhunen-Loeve (KL) expansion.

In the PCC, the Brownian path is approximated by 
$$\begin{pmatrix}W(t_1)\\W(t_2)\\\vdots\\W(t_n)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\\vdots\\ a_{n1}Z_1\end{pmatrix}Z_1 + \ldots + \begin{pmatrix}a_{1n} \\a_{2n}\\\vdots\\a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}Z_n$$ with $Z_i$ independent random $N(0,1)$ variables. This is a valid construction of the discrete Brownian path if $AA^T$ is the covariance matrix $C$ of $W = (W(t_1),\ldots,W(t_n))^T$. Specifically, $a_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}v_i, i = 1,\ldots, n$, where $\lambda_1 >\lambda_2>\ldots >\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $C$ and the $v_i$ are the corresponding eigenvectors.

Alternatively, in the KL expansion the Brownian path is equal to $$W(t) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \sqrt{\lambda_i}\psi(t)Z_i, 0\leq t \leq 1, $$  with $Z_i$ again independent random $N(0,1)$ variables. This infinite series an exact representation of the continuous Brownian path. By taking just the first $k$ terms in this series, we arrive at an approximation to the continuous path $\{W(t), 0\leq t\leq1\}$ that apparently is optimal in the sense of explained variability.

I'm trying to compare these methods, and basically the only difference I can think of is the coefficients. For PCC we have that $$\lambda_i = \dfrac{\Delta t}{4}\sin^{-2}\bigg(\dfrac{2i - 1}{2n + 1}\dfrac{\pi}{2}\bigg), v_i(j) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2n + 1}}\sin\bigg(\dfrac{2i - 1}{2n + 1} j\pi\bigg), j = 1,\ldots, n$$ and for KL we have: $$\lambda_i = \bigg(\dfrac{2}{(2i +1)\pi}\bigg)^2, \psi_i = \sqrt{2}\sin\bigg(\dfrac{(2i + 1)\pi t}{2}\bigg)$$

**Question:** What are the advantages/disadvantages of these methods? When comparing the differences between these approximations at time $t$, what do we get? That is, what is $PCC_k(t) - KL_k(t)$ in general, where $k$ is the number of random normals used?

**Edit:** Perhaps, instead of answering my initial question, could somehow give me some hints on how I should analyse the coefficients of the different methods? I've tried looking at what they might be for different values for $i$ and $t$, but I didn't get very far.

Comment: The first one just says "sample a multivariate Gaussian with the right mean and covariance for the selected times". The second one says "build a random Fourier series with the right mean and, in the limit, the right covariance for all times". They really give different sorts of objects, unless you do some interpolation procedure for the first one (such as a piecewise linear construction).

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your comment! Could you explain when you would prefer the one over the other?

Comment: For analysis the second one is probably better because it is exact; going from the first one to a representation of the whole path requires some abstract "Kolmogorov extension" which is messy. The second one is also ideal when you are dealing with power spectra (meaning Fourier domain considerations). The first one gets the distribution exactly right for the points that you sample from (modulo error in our method for generating normal random variables), which is nice for more practical use.